# PHP __DIR__ efficiency

Tags: php

I have a question about the magic variables. Are these true variables or are they a type of function call? Being as how PHP is an interpreted language I am very picky about how I assign variables. I do not like to call a function multiple times if I can store the response in a variable and reuse it without costing the CPU time over and over. Currently, I assign **DIR** to a local variable and use that variable for all of my includes and anything that requires a current directory path. I am wondering if this is saving CPU time for running a function. I have spent some time looking around the internet but I can't find anything that says how these magic variables are assigned.

example

```
$dir = __DIR__;

require_once $dir . 'Some Class to Include';
require_once $dir . 'Another Class';
```

Comment: To my understanding `__DIR__` is a [Predefined Constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) -- That is actually created only once.  The difference is, that (from what I've read) it is created once whether it is called or not...   Might as well use it, if it's created and just sitting there ..

Comment: You are [wasting](https://www.amitmerchant.com/premature-optimization-is-dangerous/) your [time](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: Thank you all very much. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All these "magical" constants are resolved at compile time, unlike regular constants, which are resolved at runtime.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php

So no, you are not saving any CPU time